# Problem with adding path using zsh

Tags: environment-variables, paths, zsh, .profile, binary

I added a directory modifying `~/.profile` and adding `export PATH=$PATH:/home/...`etc etc. But I realized that using zsh terminal I couldn't use the recently installed binary until I logged out from zsh.

Thanks in advance.

(Using GNOME and Bash)

Comment: Can you show us what the command `echo $PATH` outputs when run in zsh.

Comment: Hi, here's the result > 
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/opt/bib/active/bin

Comment: Is that `/opt/bib/active/bin` folder the directory you tried to add?

Comment: Please see [this answer](http://superuser.com/questions/187639/zsh-not-hitting-profile#answer-892248).

Comment: No, I tried to add "export PATH=$PATH:/home/andrelo/Desktop/ONA/OMA/bin" to the end of ~/.profile. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Did you try `~/.zprofile` as suggested in that superuser.com answer?

Comment: regarding that answer in the link, emulate sh && . ~/.profile && emulate zsh
didn't work for me. ~/.zprofile appears as empty.

Comment: The idea is to put `export PATH=$PATH:/home/...` into `~/.zprofile`. Then it won't be empty. ;)

Comment: Thanks, but will it still read the other folders put in the path of .profile (like opt/bib/...). Or after I add several PATH in .profile how could I tell zprofile to read all of them?

Comment: As regards `/opt/bib/...` you have apparently put it somewhere else but `~/.profile` (also), or else it wouldn't have been included in the zsh-PATH. Anyway, I suppose you can put the command `source .profile` or `. .profile` into `~/.zprofile`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current "zsh terminal" has to be told to reread `~/.profile` to see the changed contents.

```
  source ~/.profile
```

should do the trick.

Comment: I typed that, back in the zsh shell but that didn't work. I logged out but still can't run the binary. Could you give me more details on how to do it? Thanks